# query set lost when page changes in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I created a search system for my objects called **Property** and it filters and search through my objects well in first page but when I change pagination or ordering or changing page all filters gone and it sends all objects to template. is there anyway to fix this?
for example this is my first url after search:

```
/properties/search?location=&category=flat&look_for=FR
```

after switching to page 2 I get:

```
/properties/search?page=2
```

and the result of my search dissappeard.

my pagination in template:

```
               {% if is_paginated %}
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                  <li>
                    <a href="?page=1" aria-label="First">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">First</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                  {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                    <li class="active"><a href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a></li>
                  {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3'%}
                    <li><a href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                  <li>
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a>
                  <li>
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}" aria-label="Last">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">Last</span></a>
                {% endif %}
              {%endif%}
```

views.py

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = Property
    template_name = 'property/properties-list.html'
    context_object_name = 'properties'
    ordering = '-pub_date'
    paginate_by = 8
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        """somthing"""
        return context
    
    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        if self.request.GET.get("paginate_by") == "":
            return self.paginate_by
        return self.request.GET.get("paginate_by", self.paginate_by)
           
    def get_ordering(self):
        ordering = super(SearchView, self).get_ordering()
        if self.request.GET.get('sort_by') == "Name":
            return ('-title')
        elif self.request.GET.get('sort_by') == "Price":
            return ('-price')
        elif self.request.GET.get('sort_by') == "Date":
            return ('-pub_date')
        else:
            return self.ordering
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        location = self.request.GET.get('location')
        category = self.request.GET.get('category')
        look_for = self.request.GET.get('look_for')
        if location or category or look_for:
            if look_for == '' and category == '':
                queryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(city__icontains = location))
            elif look_for == '':
                queryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(city__icontains = location) & Q(category__slug = category))
            elif category == '':
                queryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(city__icontains = location) & Q(property_status = look_for))
            else:
                queryset = Property.objects.filter(Q(city__icontains = location) & Q(category__slug = category) & Q(property_status = look_for))
        else:
            queryset = Property.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

url.py

```
  path("properties/search", views.SearchView.as_view(), name = "Search")
```

Obviously I'm new to Django, if you have any recommendation to improve my code, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: "but when I change pagination or ordering or changing page all filters gone" What is the exact URL that is requested when you change pagination? Be sure that it includes all of the query parameters for ordering and filters.

Comment: If you need additional details about how to do this, please [edit] your question to show the `property/properties-list.html` template.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added my pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
```

Remember that HTTP is stateless. It doesn't automatically keep track of sorting or filtering options. Here you only include `page` in the query parameters, so this is the only option that is known when the user clicks the "next" button. One solution to maintain filtering or sort order is to include the appropriate query parameters in the `href` of all `<a>` tags.